# Avoid sonarqube analysis of source code automatically generated

Tags: debugging, sonarqube, thrift, generated-code

my project generates at runtime source code from thrift file. Is there a way to avoid Sonarqube analyzes this source code automatically generated? This because I have some code smell and bug detected by Sonarqube in that generated code I can't modify and correct.

Comment: "*This because I have some code smell and bug detected by Sonarqube in that generated code I can't modify and correct.*"   --  Actually you can, in a way. If you think the code smells found are legit, why not [file a ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/THRIFT) so the Thrift compiler can be improved by someone? And if you really want, you could even implement the patch yourself and [send us a pull request](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute.html). How cool is that? It's called Open Source ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Excluding the source files or any other files from sonar analysis is possible, by using `sonar.exclusions` property in your **sonar.properties**

For example, if your source file generated is `xyz.java` in some folder say **target**, so you can exclude the file, like this

`sonar.exclusions=**/target/*.java`

or you can give the file name directly

`sonar.exclusions=**/target/xyz.java`

You can find more details here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/